# Can chisel print macros into the RTL

Tags: printing, chisel

Could you enlight whether there is a way to print macros like

```
`synthesis_on
`synthesis_keep_hiear
```

into the RTL?

Answer (score 0):

There currently is not. Would you mind [filing an issue on the Firrtl repository](https://github.com/freechipsproject/firrtl/issues/new) with more details about your use case?

Comment: sure, but I think it could be very messy, that firrtl also need to be updated to deal with the macros, which I don't know how....